# Archive widget - limit number of months to 12

Tags: archives

The default Archive widget display monthly archives in a dropdown.

I would like to limit the number of months to 12 (in dropdown).

What filter I should apply in my functions.php?

I tried this, but it gives me parsed error:

```
add_filter('WP_Widget_Archives','set_number_months');
function set_number_months($args) {
$args = array('number'    => 12);
return $args;
}
```

I also tried with wp_get_archives but same parsed error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `widget_archives_args` filter to add the archives limit.

```
function my_limit_archives( $args ) {
    $args['limit'] = 12;
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'widget_archives_args', 'my_limit_archives' );
```

And to limit the number of months in Archives widget dropdown use the following drop down filter.

```
add_filter( 'widget_archives_dropdown_args', 'my_limit_archives' );
```

Comment: I tried, it did not limit to 12. Any more ideas? thanks

Comment: Sorry I missed the dropdown part. I have updated my answer with the dropdown filter too.

Comment: +1 how to add HTML below the archives widget?

Comment: Can this same approach be used to add a class to the dropdown select element?