# How to limit wp_get_archives to show months for the X years only

Tags: widgets, archives, wp-get-archives

Can anybody show me how to set a limit on wp_get_archives to show archives by month BUT only those for the year 2010 and above - so the 2009 monthly archives are not shown on the sidebar archive widget.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If using "regular" query in theme file (**sidebar.php** for example), this code will help do the trick:

```
<?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly&limit=12'); ?>
```

The above (and below) will only show the last 12 months.

However if using a widget, then add this code to your **functions.php** file:

```
function my_limit_archives( $args ) {
    $args['limit'] = 12;
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'widget_archives_args', 'my_limit_archives' );
add_filter( 'widget_archives_dropdown_args', 'my_limit_archives' );
```

Note: In both of the above code examples, I don't remember where I got the original code from (Google can probably find it?). I just pulled this from a fix I effected on another theme.

Finally, this resource may help point you in the direction to list archives only from 2010 to the present: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-customize-the-display-of-wordpress-archives-in-your-sidebar/

I hope the above helps you in some way! :)

Comment: Further: I found this resource which may help: [http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/archives-by-year-1] See the comment that discusses `[archives type=yearly=2009]` I found the source for the above here: [http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19945/archive-widget-limit-number-of-months-to-12]